# nemo-dropbox won't install on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, dropbox, nemo

When I try to install nemo-dropbox from Synaptic I get the message,

```
Could not mark all packages for installation or upgrade
The following packages have unresolved dependencies.
Make sure that all required repositories are added and
enabled in the preferences 
nemo-dropbox: Depends: dropbox but it is not installable.
```

When I run `sudo apt install nemo-dropbox` I get the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 
requested an impossible situation or if you are
using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  nemo-dropbox :
Depends: dropbox but it is not installable E: Unable to correct
problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've found several repositories around the web for various versions of nemo, but I don't know which (if any) is proper for Ubuntu 18.04. Or is there some other solution to my problem?

EDIT:  Output of apt-cache policy nemo nemo-dropbox:

```
nemo:
  Installed: 4.0.6-1~bionic0
  Candidate: 4.0.6-1~bionic0
  Version table:
 *** 4.0.6-1~bionic0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.6.5-1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
nemo-dropbox:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4.0.0-1~bionic0
  Version table:
     4.0.0-1~bionic0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/embrosyn/cinnamon/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

Does this answer the question about what repositories I'm using? If not, how would I find the answer? (I installed Nemo so long ago I don't remember whether I added repos or not.)

Comment: Please add output of the `apt-cache policy nemo nemo-dropbox` to the question. Do you use third-party repositories or PPAs for Nemo and/or Dropbox?